# Write a Python method to generate typos based on a string

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I could just add in something that creates typos based on Levenshtein distance of two, or something like that, or reverse-engineer [Norvig's article on spellchecking](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

However, what are the most common ways to typos?

Has somebody written a method?

Comment: I feel Levenshtein distance would not be enough on it's own because it does not take into account the keyboard, for example qitten and kitten should measure as much larger distance than, say, kittdn and kitten (on a qwerty keyboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as general typo generation algorithm because this kind of algorithm depends on the target language and application - ie to generate spam domains you basically need to apply following strategies (using meta.stackoverflow.com as an example):

1. missing dots: met**as**tackoverflow.com (should be easy ;)
2. character insertion: meta.stackoverflo**ww**.com (just add a dupe of every character)
3. character omission: meta.stackoverf**lw**.com (just drop a character)
4. character permutation: meta.stackove**fr**low.com (pure mathematics here)
5. character replacement: meta.**d**tackoverflow.com (now here we can have at least two strategies, see below)

In case of character replacement we can have at least two scenarios:

1. Similar sounding letters (ie c <-> k, z <-> ts ) depending on language
2. Nearby letters proximity typos (ie for qwerty s <-> d, d <-> f) *Duh, I actually made a typo here with s <-> d case :)*

Hope this helps..

Comment: Oh, by the way, there are two typos in your username. It's "please", you know.

Comment: Interestingly, I asked a question whether some kind of Levenshtein distance exists taking into account your 2nd "character replacement scenario (keyboard proximity). Do you perhaps know any?

Comment: @PascalvKooten Maybe this: http://search.cpan.org/~krburton/String-KeyboardDistance-1.01/KeyboardDistance.pm